# How can I get all the Groups from Azure via the Graph API for which I am an owner?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to query Azure via the Graph API to find which Groups I own (or am one of multiple owners).  The closest query I've been able to find is:

```
/users/{userId}/ownedObjects
```

This returns different types of objects, including Groups.  However, it appears to return items that are NOT in fact owned by user `{userId}`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hi, Are you meaning Azure AD groups ? or Azure tenants as group ?. Appreciate your clarification :)

Comment: Yes - Azure AD groups.  I did find a Graph API to find all objects owned by a user - /users/{userId}/ownedObjects - but I found that it returned groups that were in fact NOT owned by user {userId}.

Comment: Did you use this API, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0 ?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the solution.  Members aren't necessarily owners, and owners aren't necessarily members of groups.

Comment: OK. So you need groups that u administrate ? I'll check and update you